# What is the correct way to update properties on a Bluetooth Low-Energy device in Angular.js?

Tags: html, angularjs, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know there is a better way of achieving what I will describe below.

Let's say I have a few identical Bluetooth LE devices which I load into an array:

```
var bleDevices = [];
```

There are some indicators and switches which need to be updated on the user interface using the properties above. The devices are attached to the DOM like so:

```
$scope.devices = getAllDevices();
```

Each device has a bunch of properties associated with it which represent the current state of the physical peripheral device.

```
onDeviceDiscoveryCallback(device){

   addDeviceToArray({

    /** The first three properties are returned by the callback */
    name:device.name,
    rssi:device.rssi,
    id:device.id

    /** The rest of the object contains developer defined properties */
    acceleration:null,
    temperature:null,
    brightness:null,
    .
    .
    .

  })
 }
```

After filling the array with the above devices, I then connect to a device. The onConnect callback returns a device object, the ID of which I use to grab my device from the array:

```
onConnectCallback(device){

 var arrayDevice = getDeviceByID(device.id);

}
```

I then proceed to update the properties as required throughout the various factories like so:

```
var updateAcceleration = function(arrayDevice){

  arrayDevice.acceleration = someValue;
};
```

This is happening in a factory so $scope isn't available. Instead, I use $rootScope everywhere which appears to work but is very unmanageable as the application is quite large and complex partly due to the way I'm binding the model to the interface.

My question is, is there a better way to update my user interface by having a central BLE device object?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I had hard time following the question. A more concrete example with larger snippets (including the place they appear) might help.

Nevertheless, data management in Angular (incl. third party changes) is generally similar, so I can try to propose a way:

## Make a factory own bluetooth data/state

Services are singletons, and they provide a good place to store application-wide singleton data + logic. I suggest you to have a `Bluetooth` factory with

`getAllDevices() // returns data that you want to show on screen`
and if you need to update anything bluetooth data related `updateData()` maybe.

In any controller, you can inject `Bluetooth` factory and you can use `$scope.devices = Bluetooth.getAllDevices();` without worrying about scope chaining etc.

## Let Angular know about outside changes

If you change something in application from a third party callback (say that `onDeviceDiscoveryCallback` function of your 3rd party library, and if you change something in the application in this function, angular will have no idea about the change and screen will not be updated. You can inject `$rootScope` to your factory and use `$rootScope.$digest()` after you are done to notify angular that, something changed by a 3rd party.

## Conclusion

```
angular.factory("Bluetooh", function($rootScope) {
  var devicesData = []; 

  thirdPartyBTLibrary.onDeviceDiscovery(function (device) {
     devicesDara.push(device);
     $rootScope.$digest(); // yo angular, there is an updat
  });

  return {
     getDevicesData: function() { return devicesData; }
  }
})


angular.controller("random", function(Bluetooh) {
   $scope.devices = Bluetooh.getDevicesData();
});
```

We used `$rootScope` only to notify outer changes and not polluted it.
We made a singleton entity source of truth and isolated update logic there.
We got our data from this entity as much as we want and displayed on screen.